# Foreign Keys Error MySQL(XAMPP) - (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, xampp, foreign-keys, schema

I'm currently learning MySQL via xampp , and when trying to reference FKs I keep getting a error telling me they haven't been called correctly - "errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" to be precise. Not sure if I am missing something in my query but as far as I am aware it is using the InnoDB but below is what I tried..

```
CREATE TABLE Drivers(
Driver_ID int NOT NULL,
Driver_FName varchar(255),
Driver_Lname varchar (255),
Shift_Pattern varchar (255),
PRIMARY KEY (Driver_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE GPS(
GPS_ID int NOT NULL,
GPS_Location varchar(255),
Driver_ID int NOT NULL,
Driver_FName varchar(255),
Time_Of_Day timestamp,
FOREIGN KEY (`Driver_ID`) REFERENCES `Drivers` (`Driver_ID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`Driver_FName`) REFERENCES `Drivers` (`Driver_FName`),
PRIMARY KEY (`GPS_ID`)
);
```

Even when I try to create them separately , I still get the same error despite the references already existing in Drivers table. Should I be adding the back slashes to very column name?

Comment: You also need indexes on the referenced columns. You don't have one on drivers.driver_fname.

Comment: @P.Salmon oooh got it , thanks a lot ! Is working now

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out , the columns that will be referenced as FKs need to be indexed.
I used

```
ALTER TABLE `Drivers` ADD INDEX (`Drivers_FName`);
```